SQL - Extracting dates within a range spanning multiple years
In an mySQL Database (version 5.7.44) I have a number of records (>30,000) from which I want to search those inside a supplied range of dates.
The target column is a Date field named 'data' with format 'Y-mm-dd' in the table 'Visits'.
My application sends to the PHP function 2 STRINGS in the same format (i.e. 2023-05-01 and 2024-05-01).
This is stripped code of my PHP function:
$sDate = $_GET['start'];    //2023-05-01
$eDate = $_GET['end'];      //2024-05-01

$start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($sDate)); //check OK with echo
$end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($eDate));  //check OK with echo

$query = "SELECT data FROM Visits WHERE 
data BETWEEN '".$start."' AND '".$end."' GROUP BY MONTH(data) ORDER BY data ASC";

The query runs almost good, but I only get the rows for the first year (2023) and nothing for the months in 2024.
I suspect that the BETWEEN clausole is the origin of the problem.
What I'm doing wrong?

Are you saying you get months 5-12, but not months 1-4?

Expect for the error Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.Visits.data' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by if  sql_mode only_full_group_by is enaabled I can not reproduce https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/daMHVzaXwDbAdtxHKDuNTx/0. Please reproduce your issue

Exactly what happens, aynber

Sorry, but I'm old and dumb; I do not understand anything of your comment. Which is the 'Expression #1 of SELECT' ? What does it mean  'contains nonaggregated column 'test.Visits.data' ( what is this?) ?. I do not know, nor I use, fiddle.

@Orionis that's the error message your query produces if mysql's default only_full_group_by setting is enabled (which it ought to be, really). With that setting switched off, your query still works, according to the DBFiddle. It doesn't matter if you didn't use a fiddle before - now is your chance to see what it can do. For cases like this it's a great way to communicate, because we can add code and data to it, and test it for everyone to see. ErgestBasha has used it to demonstrate that the problem you're claiming to have doesn't exist, based on the code you've provided...

Do you have any data after 2023-12-31? Can you show a small sample of the data that you have?

... the only thing you didn't provide is some sample data, so ErgestBasha had to make some up based on what you seem to be trying to return in the query. Therefore, we have assume that either a) there's something about your query which you didn't tell us, or b) the reason you don't see data for 2024 is because there isn't any in your database, or because the GET parameters didn't contain what you think they did. Please ensure you [edit] your question to provide a [mre] of the issue, if you need further help

P.S. I'm not sure where you've been learning from, but this is totally the wrong way to build a SQL query using PHP when you're incorporating user input into it. 1) It's vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and 2) it can be crashed with simple syntax issues due to the input values from the client-side (even if you do client-side validation, that can be bypassed if people decide to do so)

Instead you must use prepared statements and parameters to correctly build the query and insert the values safely. See How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement, How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP? and https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli for some excellent resources and simple examples of how to do this stuff properly. Even as a beginner on a practice project you should get into good habits.

Why don't you use proper date columns for this?

GROUP BY MONTH(data) will only get you one record for each month - the year isn't even part of that grouping. So all records for May 2023 and May 2024 would be consolidated into one single record for "May". (It might not make that much of a difference, if the interval you are trying to select only covers the range of exactly one year. But you said nothing about that necessarily always being the case, with what you need to select.)

If I were you, I would use a prepared statement, this is the sample code you could use.
Using MySQLi,
$servername = "localhost"; // Your database host
$username = "username"; // Your database username
$password = "password"; // Your database password
$dbname = "myDB"; // Your database name

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sDate = $_GET['start']; // e.g., 2023-05-01
$eDate = $_GET['end'];   // e.g., 2024-05-01

// Prepare and bind the SQL statement
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT data FROM Visits WHERE data BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY data ASC");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $sDate, $eDate); // 'ss' indicates that both parameters are strings

// Execute the statement
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row['data'] . "<br>";
}

OR Using PDO,
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDB;charset=utf8mb4'; // Update with your DB details
$username = 'username'; // Your database username
$password = 'password'; // Your database password

// Create a new PDO instance
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sDate = $_GET['start']; // e.g., 2023-05-01
$eDate = $_GET['end'];   // e.g., 2024-05-01

// Prepare the SQL statement with placeholders
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT data FROM Visits WHERE data BETWEEN :start AND :end ORDER BY data ASC");

// Bind parameters to the placeholders
$stmt->bindParam(':start', $sDate);
$stmt->bindParam(':end', $eDate);

// Execute the statement
$stmt->execute();
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    echo $row['data'] . "<br>";
}

Reason:

The issue you are encountering with your SQL query is likely related
to the GROUP BY clause in your query. When you group by MONTH(data),
you are aggregating the results by month, which means that only one
record per month will be returned. If there are multiple records for a
month, only one will be shown, and if there are no records for a month
in 2024, it will not return any results for that year.

So if you run the fiddle sample here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/daMHVzaXwDbAdtxHKDuNTx/1 shared by @Ergest Basha in the comment you will understand why he points the error on the comment.

Well, I fixed the problem at the end, but I must say that I do not understand the policies of this site that I joined 9 years ago.
The topic was closed saying  'Add details and clarify the problem you’re solving'. Which other details were needed? I lost 10 reputatrion points with this topic, which I do not minimum care, but why?
I'm in something like 20 forums of different topics and sadly I find this one too  severe and restrictive, not to much addressed to help people who is not high level expert.
Possibly I will be banned, obscurated or jailed...but I will survive anyway.

@Orionis I also agreed with you, "Which other details were needed?", they expect we will share the "whole codebase" to make it understandable the problem, just kidding :) . I also face this kind of issue.

@Orionis you did not provide some data examples which will produce your error. In that case would be much easier to fix your problem and not keep guessing. I provide a testing environment so you could add some data and reproduce the problem, the question wasnt updated. By the way we still have not learned the issue.
